# RxJava's Observable's onNext is sometimes skipped

Tags: android, kotlin, observable, rx-java

This is an example of two threads looping around 100ms.
The peculiar thing is that the way to loop around is not while(true), etc., but the way to add the item to the Observable with onNext after execution.

The code written in kotlin is shown below.

```
private val _ps_2_thread_loop = PublishSubject.create<Array<Any>>()

fun start() {
    _ps_2_thread_loop
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .map {
            val cmd = it[0] as String

            when(cmd) {
                "cmd0" -> {
                    LogEx.d("cmd0 start")
                    runBlocking { delay(100) }
                    LogEx.d("cmd0 fin")
                    _ps_2_thread_loop.onNext(arrayOf("cmd0"))
                }
            }

            return@map it
        }
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .map {
            val cmd = it[0] as String

            when(cmd) {
                "cmd1" -> {
                    LogEx.d("cmd1 start")
                    runBlocking { delay(100) }
                    LogEx.d("cmd1 fin")
                    _ps_2_thread_loop.onNext(arrayOf("cmd1"))
                }
            }

            return@map it
        }
        .subscribe()

    _ps_2_thread_loop.onNext(arrayOf("cmd0"))
    _ps_2_thread_loop.onNext(arrayOf("cmd1"))
}
```

The expected result is that cmd0 and cmd1 are logged forever.
However, either cmd0 or cmd1 is canceled in the middle.
On log, it seems to work fine until onNext, but it seems to be skipped somewhere after Observable, ie RxJava.

The log is shown below.

```
07-03 16:02:26.010 24540 24638 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:759:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 start
07-03 16:02:26.137 24540 24638 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:761:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 fin
07-03 16:02:26.140 24540 24638 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:759:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 start
07-03 16:02:26.141 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:774:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 start
07-03 16:02:26.242 24540 24638 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:761:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 fin
07-03 16:02:26.243 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:776:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 fin
07-03 16:02:26.243 24540 24638 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:759:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 start
07-03 16:02:26.345 24540 24638 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:761:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 fin
07-03 16:02:26.346 24540 24638 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:759:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 start
07-03 16:02:26.346 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:774:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 start
07-03 16:02:26.448 24540 24638 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:761:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 fin
07-03 16:02:26.448 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:776:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 fin
07-03 16:02:26.449 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:774:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 start
07-03 16:02:26.552 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:776:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 fin
07-03 16:02:26.554 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:774:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 start
07-03 16:02:26.658 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:776:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 fin
07-03 16:02:26.660 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:774:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 start
07-03 16:02:26.763 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:776:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 fin
07-03 16:02:26.766 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:774:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 start
07-03 16:02:26.867 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:776:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 fin
07-03 16:02:26.870 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:774:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 start
07-03 16:02:26.972 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:776:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 fin
07-03 16:02:26.975 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:774:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 start
07-03 16:02:27.077 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:776:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 fin
07-03 16:02:27.080 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:774:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 start
07-03 16:02:27.183 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:776:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 fin
07-03 16:02:27.186 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:774:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 start
07-03 16:02:27.289 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:776:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 fin
07-03 16:02:27.292 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:774:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 start
07-03 16:02:27.394 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:776:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 fin
07-03 16:02:27.397 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:774:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 start
07-03 16:02:27.500 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:776:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 fin
07-03 16:02:27.503 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:774:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 start
07-03 16:02:27.607 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:776:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 fin
07-03 16:02:27.610 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:774:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 start
07-03 16:02:27.715 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:776:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 fin
07-03 16:02:27.719 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:774:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 start
07-03 16:02:27.823 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:776:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 fin
07-03 16:02:27.826 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:774:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 start
07-03 16:02:27.930 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:776:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 fin
07-03 16:02:27.933 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:774:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 start
07-03 16:02:28.037 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:776:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 fin
07-03 16:02:28.040 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:774:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 start
07-03 16:02:28.143 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:776:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 fin
07-03 16:02:28.146 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:774:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 start
07-03 16:02:28.249 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:776:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 fin
07-03 16:02:28.252 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:774:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 start
07-03 16:02:28.356 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:776:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 fin
07-03 16:02:28.359 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:774:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 start
07-03 16:02:28.463 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:776:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 fin
07-03 16:02:28.466 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:774:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 start
07-03 16:02:28.569 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:776:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 fin
07-03 16:02:28.572 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:774:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 start
07-03 16:02:28.675 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:776:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 fin
07-03 16:02:28.678 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:774:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 start
07-03 16:02:28.784 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:776:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 fin
07-03 16:02:28.789 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:774:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 start
07-03 16:02:28.892 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:776:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 fin
07-03 16:02:28.896 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:774:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 start
07-03 16:02:28.999 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:776:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 fin
07-03 16:02:29.002 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:774:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 start
07-03 16:02:29.107 24540 24639 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:776:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 fin
...
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing some additional debugging on my own, I made some progress.

It seems that you should not call onNext of Observable (in this case _ps_2_thread_loop) during the operation.
Calling `_ps_2_thread_loop.onNext(arrayOf("cmd0"))` in the map looks like a goto statement as a kind of antipattern.
I haven't debugged RxJava internals, but this seems to be a problem.

So, after exiting the map by returning specifically from the part where onnext is needed, collect it in the 3rd thread and process onnext at once, and it is actually executed normally.

code:

```
private val _ps_2_thread_loop = PublishSubject.create<Array<Any>>()

fun _48_2_thread_loop() {
    _ps_2_thread_loop
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .map {
            val cmd = it[0] as String

            when (cmd) {
                "cmd0" -> {
                    LogEx.d("cmd0 start")
                    runBlocking { delay(100) }
                    LogEx.d("cmd0 fin")
                    return@map arrayOf("onnext", arrayOf("cmd0"))
                }
            }
            return@map it
        }
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .map {
            val cmd = it[0] as String

            when (cmd) {
                "cmd1" -> {
                    LogEx.d("cmd1 start")
                    runBlocking { delay(100) }
                    LogEx.d("cmd1 fin")
                    return@map arrayOf("onnext", arrayOf("cmd1"))
                }
            }
            return@map it
        }
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .map {
            val cmd = it[0] as String

            when (cmd) {
                "onnext" -> {
                    val onnextArray = it[1] as Array<Any>
                    _ps_2_thread_loop.onNext(onnextArray)
                }
            }

            return@map it
        }
        .subscribe()

    _ps_2_thread_loop.onNext(arrayOf("cmd0"))
    _ps_2_thread_loop.onNext(arrayOf("cmd1"))
}
```

Log:

```
07-03 17:39:51.716 13252 13914 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:760:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 start
07-03 17:39:51.840 13252 13914 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:762:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 fin
07-03 17:39:51.843 13252 13915 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:774:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 start
07-03 17:39:51.844 13252 13914 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:760:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 start
07-03 17:39:51.947 13252 13915 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:776:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 fin
07-03 17:39:51.947 13252 13914 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:762:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 fin
07-03 17:39:51.949 13252 13914 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:760:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 start
07-03 17:39:51.949 13252 13915 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:774:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 start
07-03 17:39:52.051 13252 13914 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:762:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 fin
07-03 17:39:52.051 13252 13915 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:776:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 fin
07-03 17:39:52.053 13252 13914 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:760:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 start
07-03 17:39:52.053 13252 13915 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:774:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 start
07-03 17:39:52.155 13252 13915 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:776:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 fin
07-03 17:39:52.155 13252 13914 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:762:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 fin
07-03 17:39:52.157 13252 13914 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:760:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 start
07-03 17:39:52.158 13252 13915 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:774:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 start
07-03 17:39:52.259 13252 13915 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:776:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 fin
07-03 17:39:52.260 13252 13914 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:762:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 fin
07-03 17:39:52.261 13252 13915 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:774:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 start
07-03 17:39:52.263 13252 13914 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:760:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 start
07-03 17:39:52.365 13252 13915 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:776:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 fin
07-03 17:39:52.366 13252 13914 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:762:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 fin
07-03 17:39:52.368 13252 13915 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:774:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 start
07-03 17:39:52.369 13252 13914 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:760:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 start
07-03 17:39:52.471 13252 13915 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:776:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 fin
07-03 17:39:52.473 13252 13914 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:762:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 fin
07-03 17:39:52.474 13252 13915 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:774:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 start
07-03 17:39:52.476 13252 13914 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:760:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 start
07-03 17:39:52.578 13252 13915 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:776:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 fin
07-03 17:39:52.578 13252 13914 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:762:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 fin
07-03 17:39:52.581 13252 13914 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:760:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 start
07-03 17:39:52.581 13252 13915 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:774:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 start
07-03 17:39:52.685 13252 13915 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:776:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 fin
07-03 17:39:52.685 13252 13914 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:762:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 fin
07-03 17:39:52.687 13252 13914 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:760:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 start
07-03 17:39:52.688 13252 13915 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:774:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 start
07-03 17:39:52.791 13252 13914 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:762:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 fin
07-03 17:39:52.791 13252 13915 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:776:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 fin
```

Additionally, this problem does not occur in the JVM, but only in the Android ART, so I think this is due to an implementation difference or a bug in the Android scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

In the above article, in order to fix the phenomenon of onNext being ignored, a new map that handles onNext is created using a new schduler and only processed here. However, this created a new problem.

Code with problem:

```
    fun _48_pipeline_single_line() {
        val ps = PublishSubject.create<Array<Any>>()

        ps
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map {
                val cmd = it[0] as String

                when (cmd) {
                    "cmd0" -> {
                        LogEx.d("cmd0 start")
                        runBlocking { delay(1_00) }
                        LogEx.d("cmd0 fin")
                        return@map arrayOf("onnext", arrayOf("cmd0"))
                    }
                }
                return@map it
            }
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map {
                val cmd = it[0] as String

                when (cmd) {
                    "cmd1" -> {
                        LogEx.d("cmd1 start")
                        runBlocking { delay(10_000) }
                        LogEx.d("cmd1 fin")
                        return@map arrayOf("onnext", arrayOf("cmd1"))
                    }
                }
                return@map it
            }
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map {
                val cmd = it[0] as String

                when (cmd) {
                    "onnext" -> {
                        val onnextArray = it[1] as Array<Any>
                        val incmd = onnextArray[0] as String
                        LogEx.d("onnext incmd[${incmd}]")
                        ps.onNext(onnextArray)
                    }
                }

                return@map it
            }
            .subscribe()


        ps.onNext(arrayOf("cmd0"))
        ps.onNext(arrayOf("cmd1"))
    }
```

Log where the problem occurred:

```
07-08 14:37:43.552 15217 15342 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:761:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 start
07-08 14:37:43.679 15217 15342 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:763:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 fin
07-08 14:37:43.682 15217 15343 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:775:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 start
07-08 14:37:43.683 15217 15344 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:791:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-3 onnext incmd[cmd0]
07-08 14:37:43.684 15217 15342 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:761:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 start
07-08 14:37:43.786 15217 15342 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:763:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 fin
07-08 14:37:53.687 15217 15343 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:777:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 fin
07-08 14:37:53.689 15217 15344 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:791:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-3 onnext incmd[cmd1]
07-08 14:37:53.690 15217 15344 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:791:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-3 onnext incmd[cmd0]
07-08 14:37:53.696 15217 15342 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:761:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 start
07-08 14:37:53.701 15217 15343 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:775:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 start
07-08 14:37:53.811 15217 15342 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:763:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 fin
```

As you can see from the log, it works fine until the second cmd0, but after that wait 10 seconds, cmd1 is terminated, and you can see that onnext proceeds thereafter. This seems to be because the Schduler is different, but it is processed in the order accumulated in the job queue.

I need to revise it again. If I judge it again correctly, cmd0 and cmd1 are operations that do not need to be processed in order, so it is unnecessary and wrong to design a pipeline. I think that it is right to manage only the operations that need to keep order by mapping them into maps. So the modified code and log...

Last modified code:

```
    fun _49_pipeline_double_line() {
        val ps0 = PublishSubject.create<String>()
        val ps1 = PublishSubject.create<String>()

        ps0
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map {
                val cmd = it as String

                when (cmd) {
                    "cmd0" -> {
                        LogEx.d("cmd0 start")
                        runBlocking { delay(1_000) }
                        LogEx.d("cmd0 fin")
                        ps0.onNext("cmd0")
                    }
                }

                return@map it
            }
            .subscribe()

        ps1
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map {
                val cmd = it as String

                when (cmd) {
                    "cmd1" -> {
                        LogEx.d("cmd1 start")
                        runBlocking { delay(10_000) }
                        LogEx.d("cmd1 fin")
                        ps1.onNext("cmd1")
                    }
                }

                return@map it
            }
            .subscribe()

        ps0.onNext("cmd0")
        ps1.onNext("cmd1")
    }
```

Last modified log:

```
07-08 14:38:08.524 15356 15426 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:834:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 start
07-08 14:38:08.524 15356 15425 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:816:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 start
07-08 14:38:09.554 15356 15425 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:818:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 fin
07-08 14:38:09.555 15356 15425 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:816:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 start
07-08 14:38:10.558 15356 15425 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:818:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 fin
07-08 14:38:10.559 15356 15425 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:816:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 start
07-08 14:38:11.563 15356 15425 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:818:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 fin
07-08 14:38:11.565 15356 15425 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:816:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 start
07-08 14:38:12.574 15356 15425 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:818:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 fin
07-08 14:38:12.577 15356 15425 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:816:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 start
07-08 14:38:13.583 15356 15425 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:818:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 fin
07-08 14:38:13.586 15356 15425 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:816:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 start
07-08 14:38:14.592 15356 15425 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:818:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 fin
07-08 14:38:14.596 15356 15425 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:816:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 start
07-08 14:38:15.607 15356 15425 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:818:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 fin
07-08 14:38:15.613 15356 15425 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:816:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 start
07-08 14:38:16.618 15356 15425 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:818:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 fin
07-08 14:38:16.620 15356 15425 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:816:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 start
07-08 14:38:17.630 15356 15425 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:818:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 fin
07-08 14:38:17.636 15356 15425 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:816:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 start
07-08 14:38:18.555 15356 15426 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:836:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 fin
07-08 14:38:18.556 15356 15426 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:834:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 cmd1 start
07-08 14:38:18.649 15356 15425 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:818:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 fin
07-08 14:38:18.653 15356 15425 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:816:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 start
07-08 14:38:19.659 15356 15425 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:818:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 fin
07-08 14:38:19.662 15356 15425 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:816:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 start
07-08 14:38:20.670 15356 15425 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:818:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 fin
07-08 14:38:20.674 15356 15425 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:816:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 start
07-08 14:38:21.680 15356 15425 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:818:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 fin
07-08 14:38:21.683 15356 15425 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:816:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 start
07-08 14:38:22.689 15356 15425 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:818:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 fin
07-08 14:38:22.692 15356 15425 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:816:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 start
07-08 14:38:23.695 15356 15425 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:818:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 fin
07-08 14:38:23.696 15356 15425 D LogEx   : MyTestActivity.kt:816:apply RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 cmd0 start
```